# how do i scrape the name Subway Menara UOA bangsar from the html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i tried to scrape the data from the website but it came back as nothing. please help me figure out how

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://subway.com.my/find-a-subway'
page_to_scrape = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text, 'html.parser')
loc = soup.find('div', id='fp_locationlist')
for outlet in loc.find('div', class_='fp_ll_holder'):
    name = outlet.find('h4').text
    print(name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is inside `<script>` element so [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) doesn't see it. To parse it you can use `re`/`json` modules, e.g.:

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://subway.com.my/find-a-subway"

html_text = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'"markerData":(\[.*?\}\]),', html_text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# print names of shops:
for d in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(d["infoBox"]["content"], "html.parser")
    print(soup.h4.text)
```

Prints:

```
...

Subway Aeon Cheras Selatan
Subway Bandar Baru Jelawat 
Subway Lumut Indah
Subway Cahaya Kota Puteri
Subway Kuala Krai
Taman Nusa Bestari
Subway Kuala Berang
Subway Sg Udang
Subway Kiara Bay
Subway Mahkota Square Kuantan
Subway Putra Ampang
Subway Sunggala Gateway
Subway Sunway Carnival
Subway Bangi Seksyen 7
```